# Trouble with sub figures

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I just started using a big template for a paper. With this template, if I `\usepackage{subfig}`, I get :

`Unsupported document class (or package) detected, (caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended`.

After some googling, it looked like I should instead do

`\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`.

However, when I do that, my figures that use `\subfloat` produce `Undefined control sequence }`. Any suggestions?
 The error is produced with this :

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[Correct position]{
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{2in} \rule{0.9\linewidth}{0pt}}
\label{fig:CatExperiments:Correct}
}
\caption{Cat sculpture in varying positions.}
\label{fig:CatExperiments}
\end{figure}
```

but is not produced if I comment that out. After more Googling, it sounds like `subfig` is deprecated, and I should use subcaption instead. So I tried

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{2in} \rule{0.9\linewidth}{0pt}}
\end{center}
\caption{Diagram of consistency function}
\label{fig:ConsistencyFunction}
\end{figure}
```

but now I get `Undefined control sequence \caption`.

Here is a minimal example (note it uses this style:
 rpi.edu/dept/arc/docs/latex-thesis/thesis.cls ):

```
\documentclass[chap]{thesis}

%\usepackage{subfig} % Error: Unsupported document class (or package) detected, (caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended. Fixed by caption=false below:
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % Error: Undefined control sequence }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[Correct position]{
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{2in} \rule{0.9\linewidth}{0pt}}
\label{fig:CatExperiments:Correct}
}
\caption{Cat sculpture in varying positions.}
\label{fig:CatExperiments}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions of what I should do to fix this?

Comment: You should tell what class you're using.

Comment: I am using \documentclass[chap]{thesis} from here http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/docs/latex-thesis/thesis.cls

Comment: I don't get any error with the first version, calling `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. Going to `caption` and `subcaption` is useless, as the class redefines `\caption` in a way that the packages can't use.

Comment: @egreg, I edited the original question with the exact code I'm trying.

Comment: I don't get any error. *What* undefined control sequence does TeX report?

Comment: All it says is (on line 18 and 13) "Undefined control sequence }". You can see why I have had a hard time figuring this out, not much to work with :)

Comment: I don't see an error with either version of the document. Adding `\listfiles` to the preamble indicates that I'm using a `caption.sty` dated 2011/11/10 and `caption3.sty` from 2011/11/01 for the first version, and just `caption3.sty` for the second version -- maybe your TeX installation is out of date? All other entries in `\listfiles` are from 2009 or earlier.

Comment: @Mike Renfro - After adding \listfiles, this is the output when running pdflatex ont he file: http://ideone.com/1KG0a

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu both have ancient versions of TeX Live packaged (at least by TeX.se's standards). If you want to keep using Debian, you'll probably want to [replace the Debian packages with vanilla TeX Live using these instructions](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html). For a quick check, you can see if your code works differently on a more recent version of TeX Live on any platform (Windows, Mac, etc.). You may also need to find the author of RPI's thesis class, too. He/she may know a fix already based off someone else having the same problem earlier.

Comment: The instructions say "Ensure that the only Debian TeX Live packages installed are tex-common, texinfo, and perhaps lmodern". Is that done with 'sudo apt-get remove tex*" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been solved on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=18243), the solution was manually updating the `caption` package by

- Downloading it from CTAN, storing in the Debian texlive texmf tree
- Running LaTeX on `caption.ins`
- Running `sudo texhash` at the command prompt.